# Compare the data of a case with a field in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to see how to compare the result of a case with a field

something like that

```
SELECT

CASE
WHEN A1.Currency_Code = 'USD' THEN A2.Unit_Price * @TIPO_DE_CAMBIO_USD
WHEN A1.Currency_Code = 'MXN' THEN A2.Unit_Price
END AS 'TIPO DE CAMBIO',

CASE 

WHEN 'data of case 1' > sh1.min_unit_price  THEN 'EXISTE UN MEJOR PRECIO'
WHEN 'dato de case 1' <= sh1.min_unit_price THEN 'NO EXISTE UN MEJOR PRECIO'
END AS 'ANALISIS DE DATOS',
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results, please.

Comment: for example I have 15 USD and an exchange rate of 19.50 so I do it in the first case 15 * 19.50 = 292.50 then in the case follow-up I have to verify if the result of 292.50 is greater than my field sh1.min_unit_price

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment. If I understand your question correctly, there are multiple ways to do this. I think the cleanest way is to wrap the query inside of another query like so:

```
SELECT  
    CASE 
    WHEN t.TIPODECAMBIO > t.min_unit_price  THEN 'EXISTE UN MEJOR PRECIO'
    WHEN t.TIPODECAMBIO <= t.min_unit_price THEN 'NO EXISTE UN MEJOR PRECIO'
    END AS ANALISISDEDATOS,
    ...
FROM(
        SELECT

        CASE
        WHEN A1.Currency_Code = 'USD' THEN A2.Unit_Price * @TIPO_DE_CAMBIO_USD
        WHEN A1.Currency_Code = 'MXN' THEN A2.Unit_Price
        END AS TIPODECAMBIO,
        sh1.min_unit_price,
        ...
        FROM ...
    ) t
```